# In code, only create a revision if a field is changed

Tags: 8, entities

I have a custom revisionable entity with a few dozen fields. I'm importing data about the entity on a periodic basis. If the entity has changed, I'd like to save it and create a new revision.

```
$dogs = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('my_entity')
  ->loadByProperties(['my_entity_id' => $my_entity_id]);

$dog = reset($dogs);

$dog->set('name', $record['TheName']);
$dog->set('birth_date', $record['Dog Birth Date']);
// Lots more ->set happening here.
$dog->set('notes', $record['Notes']);
if ($dog->someMagicComparisonFunction()) {
  $dog->setNewRevision(TRUE);
  $dog->save();
}
```

I searched for the `someMagicComparisonFunction` but didn't find it. Does it exist?

Comment: You *might* be able to create a clone before you make your changes using $cloned_node = $node->createDuplicate().  Then use the standard PhP $cloned_node == $node object comparison (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may do the trick in a `hook_entity_presave()`, or get you close:

```
$old_dog = clone $dog;
update_the_dog($dog);

// Use == to allow for out of order keys.
$same = $dog->toArray() == $old_dog->toArray();
```

This is kinda of cheating, and you may want to filter the arrays for just the fields and not the properties.  It also isn't multilingual-safe.

To do it properly, start reading `ContentEntityBase::hasTranslationChanges()` and `FieldItemList::equals()`.  The code above makes a lot of assumptions about fields and storage, which `ContentEntityBase()` does properly.

Comment: The shown code works also outside of `hook_entity_presave()`.

Comment: Thanks! I think the comparison should be `!=` if the variable is `$changed`. This comparison is testing more for a `$same` - right?

Comment: @greggles Yeah, updated the var name in the code.